# Show that $t$ defines a functor $\mathbf{Ab} \to \mathbf{Ab} $ if one defines $t(f)=f \mid_{tG}$ for every homomorphism $f$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

> For an abelian group $G$ let $$tG=\{x \in G \mid x \text{ has a finite order } \}$$ denot its torsion subgroup. Show that $t$ defines a functor $\mathbf{Ab} \to \mathbf{Ab} $ if one defines $t(f)=f \mid_{tG}$ for every homomorphism $f$.

This should follow because

1. For $f,g \in \operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ where $A,B \in \operatorname{obj} \mathbf{Ab}$ $$t(f \circ g)=(f\circ g)\mid_{tG} = f \mid_{tG} \circ g \mid_{tG} = t(f) \circ t(g)$$
2. $t(1_G)=1\mid_{tG}$

I don't quite understand why $$(f\circ g)\mid_{tG} = f \mid_{tG} \circ g \mid_{tG}$$ where does this come from?

Comment: You need more than that. You need to verify that the restriction of $f\colon A\to B$ to $tA$ has image contained in $tB$ (which is easy, but you never check). You need this in order for the restriction to actually give you a function from $tA$ to $tB$. Once you verify that, that the restriction of $f\circ g$ equals the compositon of the restrictions follows.

Comment: Why does the image have to be contained in $tB$? Aren't I working in the category $\mathbf{Ab}$ so couldn't I just have the morphisms from any abelian group to abelian group?

Comment: You are trying to define a functor. A functor $T$ is a map from Objects to Objects, and from arrows to arrows, with the property that if $f\colon A\to B$ is an arrow in your domain category, then $T(f)$ is an arrow in your target category from $T(A)$ to $T(B)$. Here, your functor sends an abelian group $A$ to the group $tA$; if the image of $f$ under the functor is going to be the restriction of $f$ to $tA$, then you **need** this resulting arrow to be a function from $tA$ to $tB$, The restriction is just a map from $tA$ to $B$. You need the codomain to work too.

Comment: So you need $t(f)$ to be an arrow from $tA$ to $tB$. That is, you need to verify that the restriction of $f$ has image containe din $tB$. Otherwise, this doesn't work at all. Once you verify this, it will be obvious why $(g\circ f)|_{tA} = (g|_{tB})\circ (f|_{tA})$.

Comment: Note, by the way, that you wrote a bit of nonsense: if $f,g\in \mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$, then you cannot talk about $f\circ g$. (unless $B=A$).

Comment: I think I understood the first part of your comment, but I still am wondering about the fact that $tA$ should be contained in $tB$. Doesn't the definition state that $A \in \operatorname{obj} \mathbf{Ab} \implies T(A) \in  \operatorname{obj} \mathbf{Ab}$? So I only would need to check that the image is again an abelian group?

Comment: "$tA$ should be contained in $tB$". **No**. What you need is to show that if $f\colon A\to B$ is an abelian group homomorphism, then the **image** of $tA$ under $f$ is contained in $tB$. You are confusing "image of the functor $T$ when applied to objects" with "image of the morphism $T(f)$ when evaluated at $tA$" (or "image of the morphism $f$ when restricted to $tA$")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ are categories, then a (covariant) functor $T\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{D}$ is a rule that:

1. Associates, to every object $A\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathscr{C})$, an object $T(A)\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathscr{D})$;
2. Associates, to every arrow $f\in\mathscr{C}(A,B)$, an arrow $T(f)\in\mathscr{D}(T(A),T(B))$, for every $A,B\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathscr{C})$;
3. Has the property that if $A,B,C\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathscr{C})$, $f\in\mathscr{C}(A,B)$, $g\in\mathscr{C}(B,C)$, then $T(g\circ f) = T(g)\circ T(f)$;
4. Has the property that if $A\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathscr{C})$, then $T(\mathrm{id}_A) = \mathrm{id}_{T(A)}$.

Here you have $\mathscr{C}=\mathscr{D}=\mathsf{Ab}$, the category of abelian groups. You are trying to define the functor $T$ by letting $T(A)=tA$, and for $f\colon A\to B$, letting $T(f)=f|_{tA}$.

It is clear that the definition satisfies 1.

In order to verify that it satisfies (2), you need to show that if $f\colon A\to B$ is a morphism of abelian groups, then $T(f)$ will be a morphism from $T(A)$ **to** $T(B)$; that is, you need to verify that if $a\in tA$, then $f(a)\in tB$. Otherwise, what you get is merely an arrow $f|_{tA}\colon tA\to B$, which is not what you need for a functor: the functor requires that $T(f)$ be a map **from** $T(A)$ **to** $T(B)$, not merely from $T(A)$ to *something* in $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathscr{D})$.

So you need to verify that a morphism $f\colon A\to B$ of abelian groups must map $tA$ into $tB$ for this association to satisfy 2. That is, this is required to even be sure that you are defining something that *could* be a functor. This is at the level of making sure that your association sends arrows $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ into arrows in $\mathrm{Hom}(tA,tB)$.

Your item (1) is not correctly written: if $f$ and $g$ are both morphisms from $A$ to $B$, then you cannot compose them unless $A=B$ (composition in categories is only defined when the codomain of the first function equals the domain of the second function), so it makes no sense to talk about $f\circ g$ at all. Rather, you need to show that if $A,B,C$ are abelian groups, $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ are morphisms, then $(g\circ f)|_{tA} = (g|_{tB})\circ(f|_{tA})$.

And of course you need to verify that $(\mathrm{id}_A)|_{tA} = \mathrm{id}_{tA}$.

Comment: Now I see what you meant! If $a \in tA$, then $a$ has a finite order so $a^n=1$ for some finite $n$. So $f(a^n) = f(a)^n$ and $f(a^n)=f(1)=1$ since $f$ is a homomorphism so $f(a)^n = 1$ implying that $f(a)$ has a finite order and thus is in $tB$?

Comment: @TienNguyen: Yes; and now the fact that the restriction of the composition is the composition of the restrictions should be clear.